# Verify Square transaction and get transaction ID

Tags: php, square

I am able to create a transaction like the following:

```
$result = $apiInstance->createPayment($body);
```

Now I am trying to verify that the payment went through and get a transaction ID.

I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
$result->getTransaction()->getId();
```

How would I go on to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The `createPayment` method returns a `CreatePaymentResponse` object, which doesn't contain a method called `getTransaction()`, but it does contain `getPayment()`. So you should change the last line to `$result-getPayment()->getId()` and it should work.

Reference: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Model/CreatePaymentResponse.md